# Cuda compilation issue in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have to port a crowd simulation application onto GPU using CUDA. For that I have this work done by Simon Boots who has ported C++ opensteer library onto CUDA successfully. But I am unable to run the CUDA version on my PC. I am attaching the link for the CUDA code but when i run it on visual studio it does not show any cuda files in solution explorer. Instead it runs the CPU version. Thanks.

Code link:

https://github.com/simonboots/OpenSteerCUDA

In short, my question is, help me compile this CUDA code. I need to use it for my learning. I am still a beginner. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for a tutorial or ReadMe that describes how to do what you are trying to do. There is probably a Preprocessor flag (#define) or script that you need to enable to tell the compiler to build the GPU version.